# Bitcode error in Xcode 8, but only for Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, bitcode

I just updated to Xcode 8, and I'm getting a new error whenever I try to use the Simulator. (Any device type in the simulator.) It reads like this...

```
'[...]/AppDelegate.o' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The trick is, Bitcode IS enabled. (And it has to be, as I'm doing Apple Watch stuff.) I've seen other questions on SO with this same error, but there are a few new wrinkles in my version that those don't address:

1. It's not some external library or something, it's my AppDelegate.
2. Bitcode IS enabled, and has been for the entire development life of this project (9+ months).
3. The project builds just fine for a physical device, a "Generic iOS Device", and for Archiving. It's only the Simulator that pops this error.

My assumption is that this is a bug or some sort of false setting in my build rules for how I'm building on the simulator, but I don't know where that would be. I've cleaned, deleted Derived Data, tried multiple simulators, and restarted both Xcode and my computer.

Anyone know what's causing this, and how I might get around it?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the derived data and cleaning the project?

Comment: @DejanSkledar Said so in the question, yeah. ;) But thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if maybe this will solve it, but in our project, with Watch Extension, we have on the app target the Bitcode Disabled and Enabled on the other targets.

And on the main app target, we have the Valid Architecture set to armv7/s arm64.

I hope this helps a bit.